# Laravel 8: не передаётся модель из контроллера в blade-шаблон

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Из контроллера, в ф-ии edit не передаётся объект в blade-шаблон генерации формы.

---

**routes\web.php:**

```
Route::middleware(['role:admin'])->prefix('admin-panel')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('adm-home');
    Route::resource('news', App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdmNewsController::class);
});
```

---

**resources\views\admin\news\edit.blade.php:**

```
<form action="{{ route('news.update', $news['id']) }}" method="POST">
@csrf
@method('PUT')
...
```

---

**app\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdmNewsController.php:**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\NewsModel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AdmNewsController extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $news_items = NewsModel::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
        return view('admin.news.index',[
            'news_items' => $news_items
        ]);
    }

    public function create() {
        return view('admin.news.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request) {
        $news_item = new NewsModel();
        $news_item->title = $request->title;
        $news_item->img = $request->img;
        $news_item->text = $request->text1;
        $news_item->tag_id = 0;
        if($request->published == 'on') {
            $news_item->published = 1;
        } else {
            $news_item->published = 0;
        }
        $news_item->save();
        return redirect()->back()->withSuccess('Новость добавлена');
    }

    public function show(NewsModel $newsModel) {
        //
    }

    public function edit(NewsModel $newsModel) {
        return view('admin.news.edit', [
            'news' => $newsModel
        ]);
    }

    public function update(Request $request, NewsModel $newsModel) {
        $newsModel->title = $request->title;
        $newsModel->save();
        return redirect()->back()->withSuccess('Новость обновлена');
    }

    public function destroy(NewsModel $newsModel) {
        //
    }
}
```

---

**php artisan route:list показывает маршруты:**

```
GET|HEAD | admin-panel | adm-home | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\HomeController@index
GET|HEAD | admin-panel/news | news.index | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdmNewsController@index
POST | admin-panel/news | news.store | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdmNewsController@store
GET|HEAD | admin-panel/news/create | news.create | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdmNewsController@create
GET|HEAD | admin-panel/news/{news} | news.show | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdmNewsController@show
PUT|PATCH | admin-panel/news/{news} | news.update | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdmNewsController@update
DELETE | admin-panel/news/{news} | news.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdmNewsController@destroy
GET|HEAD | admin-panel/news/{news}/edit | news.edit | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdmNewsController@edit
```

---

**Получаю ошибку:**
*(На странице: site.ru/admin-panel/news/10/edit)*

```
Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException
Missing required parameter for [Route: news.update] [URI: admin-panel/news/{news}] [Missing parameter: news]. (View: E:\WebServers\OpenServer\domains\site.ru\core\resources\views\admin\news\edit.blade.php)
```

Не приходит объект и параметр ID.

Если в шаблоне, для проверки, сделать замену:

```
<form action="{{ route('news.update', 10) }}" method="POST">
```

Ошибка пропадёт, страница редактирования отображается, но соотвецтвенно без заполненных полей формы.

**При вызове dd в контроллере:**

```
    public function edit(NewsModel $newsModel) {
        dd($newsModel);
    }
```

Показывает пустой объект:

```
App\Models\NewsModel {#1363 ▼
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  +preventsLazyLoading: false
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}
```

Массивы #attributes и #original пустые, в поле #table стоит null

Кэши чистил:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

Подскажите, какие проверки можно сделать, чтобы разобраться в ситуации или может увидите ошибку или дадите решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас сгенерирован роут `admin-panel/news/{news}/edit`. Обратите внимание на имя переменной `{news}`. Вы должны указать точно такое же имя в контроллере в методе `edit`.

```
public function edit(NewsModel $news) {
    return view('admin.news.edit', compact('news');
}
```

Во вью вы можете обращаться к модели `$news` как к объекту:

```
<form action="{{ route('news.update', $news->id) }}" method="POST">
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Всё решилось. Буду знать об этом моменте. Учиться и ещё раз учиться...

Answer (score 2):

`$news['id']` почти что правильно, надо так:

```
<form action="{{ route('news.update', [ 'news'=>$news['id'] ]) }}" method="POST">
@csrf
@method('PUT')
...
```

т.е. второй аргумент для фукнции `route()` это ассоциативный массив соотв-но с именованными параметрами. и имя параметра метода `edit` тоже надо поменять на `$news`

Comment: Большое спасибо! Ваш вариант так же попробовал, всё работает. Увы у меня пока не хватает репутации, чтобы отметить ваши ответы как полезные. Но я очень вам признателен, ребята!